# Modifier for the variables inside the main method

Tags: java

I have read at many places that static method can access static variables only but when I write code, I am mentioning my variables as static and my code still works.

Is anyone out there to help me understand this concept clearly?

```
public class LearnMain {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a = 1;

        System.out.println(""+a);
    }
}
```

Comment: "*static method can access static variables only*" - that is not correct. First understand what `static` does and then it will become crystal clear. Here is a good [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) on that topic. Down-vote for lack of research.

Comment: And this tutorial about variables in Java. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Answer (score -1):

static method directly  access static variable and static method bcz static method execute class name ,and static variable get memory and initialization when the class is loaded in JVM, when any variable initialization then we have call this variable but non-static method get memory when object is created. without object non static variable and non static method could't be execute.